# ion-radio don't pick the right one on first click

Tags: ionic-framework

Playing around with ionic and found a strange behavior on the first click on `ion-radio.

[image: ion-radio issue gif]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <div class="card">

          <div class="item item-divider">Social media</div>

          <ion-radio ng-model="choice" ng-value="''" icon="icon ion-social-facebook">facebook</ion-radio>

          <ion-radio ng-model="choice" ng-value="''" icon="icon ion-social-twitter">twitter</ion-radio>

          <ion-radio ng-model="choice" ng-value="''" icon="icon ion-social-youtube">youtube</ion-radio>

        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can give it a try at

http://play.ionic.io/app/9056e06acc35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be:

```
ng-model="choice" ng-value="''"
```

You have set `ng-value` as empty, so when click on any option.. `choice` is set to empty.

so,now..it try to search ng-value as empty till end in options and as all are empty it set last one as selected.

try to set `ng-value="twitter"`, means set some value to ng-value.

```
  <ion-radio ng-model="choice" ng-value="'fb'" icon="icon ion-social-facebook">facebook</ion-radio>

  <ion-radio ng-model="choice" ng-value="'twit'" icon="icon ion-social-twitter">twitter</ion-radio>

  <ion-radio ng-model="choice" ng-value="'youtube'" icon="icon ion-social-youtube">youtube</ion-radio>
```

Comment: Your answer did the trick. I'm just learning ionic and playing around to see the UI.